# Passing Python variable to JavaScript

Tags: python, html, web

I am trying to execute some JavaScript code through Python.

```
def home():
    code = """
    var regexp = new RegExp(/playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer.*?(youtube.com\/api\/timedtext.*?)"/);
    var url = regexp.exec(document.body.innerHTML)[1];
    open("caption.py?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url));
    """
    code = quote(code, safe='~()*!.\'')
    return """<a href="javascript:(function(){ code })()">YouTube Transcriber</a>"""
```

As I understand, variables from Python must be passing to JavaScript automatically, but I get the following exception in last line in JavaScript:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: code is not defined`

Comment: "As I understand, variables from Python must be passing to JavaScript automatically" no? I'm no sure why you would expect that

Answer (score 1):

You aren't telling python to put the contents of `code` into your returned string. You could do it like this:

```
return """<a href="javascript:(function(){ """ + code + """ })()">YouTube Transcriber</a>"""
```

You can't just put a variable name in a string and expect its contents to be automatically put into the string. It's not clear why you would expect that to happen. It's something you explicitly have to do, via either string formatting, or concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `return` statement, inside the JS function, there is literally the word "code", which is undefined. You probably wanted to enter the value of the variable `code` in which case you need to break the string apart, and add the `code` variable in between like this:

```py
return """<a href="javascript:(function(){""" + str(code) + """})()">YouTube Transcriber</a>"""
```